# Sum of groupBy elements using PipeTransform

Tags: asp.net, angular, asp.net-web-api

I did a **groupBy** in an `Angular` project and in back-end, using `ASP.NET Web Api` to retrieve data for the **groupBy** functionality. I used this link to make it work - [Angular groupBy](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pipe-groupby?file=src%2Fapp%2Fgroup-by.pipe.ts)  that uses **PipeTransform** interface for the implementation. It works fine and the current output is as follows right now:

```
Jack
ID   - Date       - Points
1001 - 04/01/2020 - 10
1001 - 05/01/2020 - 10

John
ID   - Date       - Points
1002 - 04/01/2020 - 10
1002 - 05/01/2020 - 20
```

So the following is the data structure:

```
data = [
{ "id": "1001", "name": "Jack", "date": "2020-01 - 05T00: 00: 00", "points": 10 },
{ "id": "1001", "name": "Jack", "date": "2020-01 - 04T00: 00: 00", "points": 10 },
{ "id": "1002", "name": "John", "date": "2020-01 - 05T00: 00: 00", "points": 20 },
{ "id": "1002", "name": "John", "date": "2020-01 - 04T00: 00: 00", "points": 10 }     
];
```

In the front-end, I did this to render the view:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 table-responsive">
    <table *ngIf="data" class="table table-responsive" border="0">
      <tbody *ngFor="let details of data | groupBy: 'name'">
        <tr>
          <th colspan="2">
             <h2>{{details.key}}</h2> <!--Here name is shown-->
          </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Sl No.</th>
          <th>Id</th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Date</th>
          <th>Points</th>
        </tr>

        <tr *ngFor="let value of details.value; let i = index">
          <td>{{i + 1}}</td>
          <td>{{value.id}}</td>
          <td>{{value.name}}</td>
          <td>{{value.date | date :'dd-MMM-yyyy'}}</td>
          <td>{{value.points}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>Total Points: {{sum}}</tr> <!--Expecting total points for groupBy-->
      </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

My expected output is as follows:

```
Jack
ID   - Date       - Points
1001 - 04/01/2020 - 10
1001 - 05/01/2020 - 10
______________________________
Total Points: 20

John
ID   - Date       - Points
1002 - 04/01/2020 - 10
1002 - 05/01/2020 - 20
______________________________
Total Points: 30
```

I am new to `stackblitz` and unable to build the project to render. Here is the link that I tried with the code - [Angular groupBy with stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ybnzzm)

**N.B**: I tried to do the sum in the `TypeScript` file like this but this does total calculation of the points, not **groupBy**:

```
public sum: number = 0;

GetUserPoints() {
  debugger;

  for (let i = 0; i <= this.data.length; i++) {
     this.sum += this.data[i].points;
     console.log(this.data.length);
  }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is missing or not working? The calculation of the sum?

Comment: Did you look in the dev tools console to see if there are any errors?

Comment: No errors actually. I am trying to get the sum @Batajus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to keep this dynamic and reusable by using pipes, you could achieve calculating the sum of points by creating a `PluckPipe` and `SumPipe` like i did in this stackblitz 
Then just use `<tr>Total Points: {{details.value | pluck:'points' | sum}}</tr>` in your template
example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-iurvtc

*btw: your stackblitz did not render because there were spaces in the timestamps.*

Comment: I tried to run the project you provided with `stackblitz` link but unfortunately the view doesn't render @A.Winnen. Am I missing something? Thanks very much for your time and effort.

Comment: are you sure? its working for me. please see browser console for errors